# C# WPF - The name "..." does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:..."

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I've been having this weird problem in my WPF project. I keep getting errors of the following format: The name "..." does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:..."

Here's a screenshot of what it actually looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrJQk.png

I've tried pretty much everything: Restarting visual studio, cleaning the solution, rebuilding the solution, reverting to an earlier point in git commit history, moving files around etc. And yes, I've done some research before posing my question here, none of the 'solutions' that I came across worked for me.

In my eyes, these errors shouldn't pop up at all as these namespaces/files simply exist and visual studio should not have any problems finding them. Here's the project on github if you're looking for more information: https://github.com/Reverp/Toxy

Now here's the fun part, visual studio can build/debug the project just fine. The only thing that doesn't work is the design view because of 'invalid markup'. But it gets even weirder, after trying it on different machines, some seemed to have the same issues but others didn't have them at all. The machines that didn't have this problem were all running Windows 8 (my machine runs 8.1), but that shouldn't matter, right?

Also, once I start working on the project despite the errors, more similar errors will start to pop up over time!

In case you want to try to reproduce this you should do the following: Clone the repository, open the solution file in visual studio and open MainWindow.xaml. After that, the errors should appear.

Has anyone had this issue before and/or do you know how to resolve it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a designer error, I get these too. My solution is to close the editor with the xaml and ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code on Github, your friend class takes a parameter on construction. Since your error is in XAML, I am guessing that parameter is not being set.

Try adding a parameterless constructor to the three types causing the issue and see if they resolve.

You will have to pass the MainViewModel as a property assignment:

```
<viewModels:MainViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" />
```

... to create an instance of your main view model

```
<viewModels:FriendControlViewModel x:Key="friends" MainViewModel="{StaticResource myMainViewModel}" />
```

... to link that to your friends :)

I know this isn't directly linked to your error, but XAML does tend to throw a wobble if there is an issue in the code - but doesn't relay that back in the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work. What did work though, was removing and re-adding the reference to SharpTox. For some odd reason, that fixed it.

Comment: I would still be surprised if your solution worked without this change. Unless you have an IOC component wiring in constructor parameters, I think this would have been an error in waiting. Glad you got it working nonetheless.